# "BE GOING TO" What verb tense is it? Why?

Tags: grammar

In wikipedia, it is stated that basic form of going-to construction is present tense, however it gives the impresssion to me like of a present continuous. Furthermore, whatever book I read it is presented as Future Tense. Would be really grateful if you could explain which tense is  "be going to"?

Comment: "Be" has no tense at all, it's the infinitive. It can be made into present tense (*am, are, is*) or into past tense (*was, were*), and that's the tense it is then in. Continuous is not a tense, but an aspect. That's what the "going" adds. But that doesn't change the actual tense, it only adds an aspect to it. Whatever tense the "be" is in, that's still the actual tense of the whole phrase. And future tense simply does not exist in English.

Comment: (1) Wikipedia is not a good source for English grammar facts. No wonder you're confused. (2) You're misrepresenting the construction; it's the ***be** going to* construction. The _be_ is part of the idiom, though it often gets dropped, especially in contractions like _gonna_. (3) The _be going to_ idiom can be either present tense (_I am, you are, he is going to_) or past tense (_I was, you were going to_), or it can be tenseless as an infinitive _be going to_ or a participle _been going to_. (4) _Be going to_ **means** future, but it's not future tense. (5) English has no future tense.

Comment: Your answers were enlightening, I got the answer I need,  but could you please direct me to a reliable source which explains why there is no future tense in English?

Comment: yes it does! what about if you will go to the shops? this all happens in the future!